# TeXShop - Don't display the latest pdf preview of the tex file when we open this tex file

Tags: pdf, texshop

Is there a way to disable the fact that when I open my tex file his previous preview pdf appear ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Delete the pdf and then open the file? :-(

Comment: Interesting thanks, but if there is another solution I would take it.

Comment: When you first open the file the previe will be active so Cmd-W will immediately close that window.

Comment: This is an action I used to do but the time passing I start to be fed up of it.. this is why I post this question, because I’m fed up of Cmd+W .. I don’t want to see this pdf window anymore when I open my Tex file .. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I suggest contacting TeXShop's developer, Dick Koch, and requesting this as a feature. He may implement it if he agrees it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I found the answer at [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/index.php?title=TeXShop&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#:%7E:text=TeXShop%20can%20be%20used%20as,Then%2C%20close%20and%20reopen%20TeXShop.)

> TeXShop can be used as a previewer for an external editor. If you want to edit your source files in a different editor, go to TeXShop > Preferences > Source, and check Configure for External Editor. Then, close and reopen TeXShop.
>
> Even if Configure for External Editor is checked in your preferences,
> always open the .tex file in TeXShop, rather than the .pdf file.
> TeXShop will open the PDF anyway